# Bulk upsert optimization mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, bulk

I have a collection with about 50 000 entries which contains some fields.

The combination of two of them is uniq (an ObjectID and a string).

I takes about 15s to upsert 500 entries. Is there a way to get it done faster ?
I tried to use bulkWrite (with ordered:false) instead of multiple updateOne() on collection with nestJS but there is no gain.

```
myObjects.forEach(objects => {
const upsertDoc = {
      updateOne: {
           filter: { someOid: myOid, someString: myString },
           update: { $set: myObject },
           upsert: true,
      },
};
bulkOps.push(upsertDoc);
}

myModel.collection.bulkWrite(bulkOps, { ordered: false });
```

I tried with an empty collection and it's a way faster (200ms), I guess that's the filter part that take too long.

Comment: Find out whether the database is cpu or disk bound when upserting.

Comment: Check one of the updateOne calls with `explain`.

Comment: Perhaps your `.forEach()` is the slow part, not the bulk update.

Comment: The graph show that mongoDB is neither CPU limited or disk limited, for the for each, it's done in less than a second, mongoDB log that a bulk update take about 14500s everytime

Comment: Can we see that log entry?

Comment: https://ibb.co/gv9BT8P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to search not over two field, but only one (simply the _id in ma case), this drastically improve performance